# SSL session resumption after close socket FD

Tags: sockets, ssl, openssl

I want to resume SSL session when I do interactive with server.

I found example in tutor (An introduction to OpenSSL programming PartII), but doubt whether it is correct.

[image: screenshot as below]

I have no idea with `close(sock)`. I doubt if I close TCP connection, session resumption can be successfully?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is correct. Session resumption allows you to resume the session with a server on a new connection. In the example above,  the session is saved using `SSL_get1_session` in the variable `sess`. The session is then resumed on the new connection by using `SSL_set_session`.  http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2011-ssl-session-reuse-rfc5077.html has a pretty good explanation of how session resumption works.